# Not compile and time out message on Overleaf

Tags: compiling, overleaf, compilation-error

I got this message:

Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams.

I have high resolution images in my script and probably that is the reason that it happens. How do I fix this?

Comment: If this is overleaf related then please tag it so. If not, please explain what you are doing as normal LaTeX does not time out.

Comment: Yes it is overleaf related! Thank you for the comment

Comment: it's not really a technical or TeX issue, you can fix it by using a smaller document (eg lower resolution images) or (I think) paying for a non free account at overleaf with more resources available. Or process the file on your local machine not at overleaf

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) We have some information about common causes of this here, in case you haven't seen it: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Why_do_I_keep_getting_the_compile_timeout_error_message%3F If none of that helps and you can't narrow down the problem to a small document whose code can be shared here, it's probably better to write us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL since the problem is probably quite project-specific.

Comment: @PaulGessler is my comment above broadly correct? (if not I'll delete)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle possibly, but we can't say for sure without seeing the project's code. :-)