Your compile timed out


I am a student and do a report in Latex. The file is large enough and began to push out errors related to labels. Tags I do using \label{metka1}
\ref{metka1}. I have not previously made such errors, but now for some reason started, what could be the problem?


Overleaf has reduced the compilation time from 1 minute to 20 seconds in the free version. The compile time of your project is more than 20 seconds, which is why you received the message "Your compile timed out".

IMHO this question is off-topic, like similar questions, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531135 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669754 etc.

You could locally install a LaTeX distribution and work offline without any timeouts.
